# How do I programmatically change the value of <input type="range" ...?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am [trying](http://jsfiddle.net/herrturtur/bBy3q/) to change the value of a range slider using the mousewheel anywhere on a page, but I don't know how to programmatically change the value of the input.

Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50">
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta){
    $('#slider').val($('#slider').val()*1 + delta);
});

// Another thing I tried, but didn't work:
/*
$('#slider').attr('value', oldval + 1);
*/
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: It works fine here (Google Chrome 9.0.597.83), but you should consider checking if the input has focus, by changing `$(window)` to `$('#slider')`

Comment: @Joshua thanks for the tip! good idea to move the slider with the mousewheel!

Comment: Also, if any browser add native support to that feature, then your solution will fail, try blocking the event too.

Comment: Seems to work fine in Firefox 3.6.13. In what browser is it not working?

Comment: @M28 focus doesn't seem to be the issue. I added an alert to the event handler and got the alert... (i'm using chrome as well)

Comment: @Caspar thanks for the kind words. good luck, and let me know if you get it to work.

Comment: @Scott I'm working in Chrome 10.0.648.6

Comment: @M28 I receive the event. The issue is with $('#slider').val(x). Basically the slider isn't updated to x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is being interpreted as a string. Use this

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta){
    $('#slider').val($('#slider').val()*1 + delta);
//    var oldval = $('#slider').attr('value');
//    if(delta > 0)
//        document.getElementById('slider').value++;
//    else
//        document.getElementById('slider').value--;
});

// Another thing I tried, but didn't work:
/*
$('#slider').attr('value', oldval + 1);
*/
```

Comment: hmm, i tried that in jsfiddle, but it didn't work. I'll try parseInt instead.

Comment: @cyberkiwi could you share the jsfiddle link?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 10.0.684.6 dev. It works in Firefox though. Unfortunately Firefox renders input type="range" as a text box.

Comment: I was using Chrome 8.0.552.. notebook and Fx 1.6 now with no mouse scroll